# safe security rules for cloud firestore (firebase) without user authentication

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I need to write safe security rules for a flutter project that doesn't require user authentication (for a reason) for creating new documents.
For all other actions you need to be authenticated.
People are only allowed to create a document if they use the app too.

Is it sufficient if I just limit the amount of created documents in a specific time (with timestamps) and also limit the size, or do I still need to consider something else?

I'm new to firebase but I kind of know that there are ways to do firebase-actions without the app (that will be creatable from the project) via commands if you just get the project-id.
For example that would be a case which I haven't considered yet.

Regarding the last point:
There are three Api keys in the google cloud platform firebase project:
An Android key, an IOS key and a browser key. (auto created by Firebase)
I thought, maybe if I'd apply a restriction to the Android key, so that only Android apps can use it and likewise for the IOS key, the problem could be solved, but I'm not sure.
(I then would restrict the keys via the Google Cloud Platform Project of the Firebase Project.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> People are only allowed to create a document if they use the app too.

This requirement is not enforceable on Firebase. Anyone can take the configuration data from your app, and use that to call the same APIs in the same way. As long as the calls meet your security rules, they will be allowed. And since there's no security rule clause that says "only from *my* app", you can't limit access to only people using your app.

> Is it sufficient if I just limit the amount of created documents in a specific time (with timestamps) and also limit the size, or do I still need to consider something else?

How do you want to limit the document creation in time? If you want to do this per user, you'll need to know the user.

I recommend looking into Firebase's anonymous authentication, which gives user's of your app an ID without requiring them to enter credentials.

Comment: I just added anonymous authentication to the app I'm currently working on. When the user sends his order to cloud firestore and he presses on "order" he will be signed in anonymously and when the order was sent to the cloud the anonymous account will be deleted. Now I can use firebase.auth in my security rules. Thank You!